# How to create a set up form that allows user to modify application properties?

Tags: c#-4.0, properties, connection-string, installation, desktop-application

For Web applications, user needs to change Database/Web Service conn-strings.
For desktop applications, user needs to change database conn-string.

How to package a desktop and web application with an set up file/installer, which allows user to modify the connection strings as per their needs using a set up form?

Comment: What have you tried? What platform and languages are you interested in using?

Comment: Right. I missed out the platform. I have two applications (web and a desktop) ready, apart from a set up forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) class will allow you to read the connection Strings.

```
using System.Configuration;

public string GetConfig(){
     return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WingtipToys"].ConnectionString;
}
```

However, it you want to modify the configuration the ConnectionStrings in file you'll have to use the XmlDocument classes. This is some what more complicated than using the ConfigurationManager and in my opinion rightly so, because changing a database connection string at the wrong time could lead to interruptions in a running set of queries and invalidate data.

```
using System.Xml;

private void ManageConfiguration()
{
    // Load Configuration
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.Load(APP_CONFIG_LOCATION);
    XmlNode xnodes = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/connectionStrings");
    if (xnodes.IsDefault()) return;

    // Read All Current Connection Strings
    foreach (XmlNode xnn in xnodes.ChildNodes) {
        if (xnn.Name == "add") {
            Console.WriteLine(xnn.Attributes["name"] + ", " + xnn.Attributes["providerName"] + ": " + xnn.Attributes["connectionString"]);
        }
    }

    // Add Connection String
    XmlNode newConnection = xdoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "add", null);

    XmlAttribute nameAttr = xdoc.CreateAttribute("name");
    XmlAttribute connectionStringAttr = xdoc.CreateAttribute("connectionString");
    XmlAttribute providerNameAttr = xdoc.CreateAttribute("providerName");

    nameAttr.Value = "New Connection";
    connectionStringAttr.Value = "..........";
    providerNameAttr.Value = "..........";

    newConnection.Attributes.Append(nameAttr);
    newConnection.Attributes.Append(connectionStringAttr);
    newConnection.Attributes.Append(providerNameAttr);

    xnodes.AppendChild(newConnection);

    // Save Configuration
    xdoc.Save(APP_CONFIG_LOCATION);
}
```

Comment: roydukkey, other than your customized solution, is there a standardized packaging methodology followed by developers who create applications with databases? It has been a real pain so far and makes no sense for developer team/support team to do the set up for users, if it can be automated for all clients. So client can do it on their own with an easy to follow set up guide.

Comment: Not as far as I know. Normally, this type of configuration wouldn't be presented during the actual installation process. Rather it would be managed by a first-run process and later accessible in a settings menu, which will be developed to suit your applications needs in design and layout.